# sending email based on a gridview column containing email addresses

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

May I know how to send email based on gridview column containing email addresses?
I am currently using asp.net and c#. I'm also currently using smtp gmail for the email.

Currently, I had a gridview1 which contain customers (email, name, accountNo) that had bounced cheque, however I wish to send an standard email, to all these customers upon clicking a button. May I know how should i go about it? Their email is stored in database and will be shown on gridview.

```
   private void SendEMail(MailMessage mail)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.Port = 587;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("@gmail.com", "password");

    try
    {
        client.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some code samples for you grid view and the gmail setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be loop through the dataset that you have bound to grid view. But since you have asked about gridview, here is how you can loop through gridview rows

On button_click write this

```
string email = "";
foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
{
      //considering 1st column contains email address
      //if not, replace it with correct index
      email =  item.Cells[0].Text;
      //code to send email

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Updating my code to use your sendEmail function

```
public void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = "";
    foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
    {

          //if not, replace it with correct index
          email =  item.Cells[4].Text;
          //code to send email
         //reciever email add
         MailAddress to = new MailAddress(email);
         //sender email address
         MailAddress from = new MailAddress("your@email");

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        //use reason shown in grid
        msg.Subject = item.Cells[3].Text;

        //you can similar extract FName, LName, Account number from grid
        // and use it in your message body
        //Keep your message body like 
        str email_msg = "Dear {0} {1}, Your cheque for account number {2} bounced because of    the reason {3}";
        msg = String.Format(email_msg , item.Cells[0].Text,item.Cells[1].Text,item.Cells[2].Text,item.Cells[3].Text);
        msg.Body = email_msg ;
        msg.From = from;
        msg.To.Add(to);

        SendEMail(msg);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to save the e-mail addresses in an array.

then do a foreach and send the e-mail that are in the array!

example:

CLASS:

```
    public SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    public MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    public System.Net.NetworkCredential smtpCreds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail", "password");

public void Send(string sendTo, string sendFrom, string subject, string body)
{
    try
    {
        //setup SMTP Host Here
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = smtpCreds;
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        //convert string to MailAdress

        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(sendTo);
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(sendFrom);

        //set up message settings

        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = body;
        msg.From = from;
        msg.To.Add(to);

        // Send E-mail

        client.Send(msg);

    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
    }
}
```

SENDING E-MAILS: (button_click)

```
//read the emails from the database and save them in an array.
//count how many are the emails, ex: int countEmails = SqlClass.Function("select emails from table").Rows.Count;

string[] emails = new string[countEmails];
foreach (string item in emails)
{
   //send e-mail
   callClass.Send(item, emailFrom, subject, body); //you can adapt the class
}
```

Comment: hi, I don't really understand your coding for the 'Sending E-mail part' Such as SQLClass.Function("select email from table").Rows.Count;
Am I suppose to do a command for it ? Like a select statement?
May I also know if the 'Sending E-mail' Am i suppose to put it in the button click ?

Comment: that was the example. 
how are you executing querys?!